# random file access in C --- shrink file?

Tags: fopen

easy question.

I want to create a set of records (database is an overstatement) on disk.  I can open with rb+, move to a random location with fseek, and then fread and fwrite, all interspersed with fflush.  all good.

now I want to delete one record.  easy---move the last record to the spot where I want to delete another record, and then shorten the file by one record.

but...how do I shorten my existing file?

/iaw

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the contents before and after the record to be deleted to
   a temporary file.
2. Delete the original file (which had the record to be deleted).
3. Rename temporary file
   as the original file.

Comment: the situation sucks.  I need to copy a gigabyte file, just to reduce its byte size count by 1??  yikes.

Answer (score 0):

To truncate the existing file that you have opened, seek to the desired file size and then set a new EOF at that position.  The problem is that C has no function for that purpose.  You would have to use platform-specific APIs, like `SetEndOfFile()` on Windows.

Comment: apparently, here is the linux equivalent:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328489/linux-set-end-of-file-shrink-truncate-cut-out-some-data-end

Comment: Yes, use `ftruncate()` on systems that support it (Windows does not).

Answer (score 0):

there is no ANSI solution to this problem, short of copying the whole file anew.

there are OS-specific solutions only.  see comments under the answers.

Windows: SetEndOfFile()
Posix: ftruncate() and truncate()